# How can one change rectangle shapes on Fabric JS

Tags: fabricjs, angular7

I am using Fabric JS on my Angular7 project.  Could you tell me how I can change the shape of the blue-colored hollow-rectangles on the corner of red-rectangle on the image?

Thanks for your attention on this post.

[Blue-colored hollow-rectangles in question is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHpSM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. Found an answer

```
object.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'blue',
    cornerStrokeColor: 'red',
    borderColor: 'red',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 10,
    cornerStyle: 'circle',
    borderDashArray: [3, 3]
  });
```

Source: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#customization